# How to get element in angularjs analog of get by id in javascript?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Lets say I have button:

```
<button type="submit"
        value="Send" 
         id="btnStoreToDB"
         class="btn btn-primary start"             
         ng-click="storeDB()"
         ng-disabled="!storeDB_button_state"
         >
                <i class="icon-white icon-share-alt"></i>
                <span>Store to DB</span>
            </button>
```

[image]

In JS to get this button I just do `var btn = $('#btnStoreToDB');` and now can play with this button. So I can take it by `id` or `class`.

But how can I get this element with `angularjs`?

I want to add spinner to button during loading like showed [here (Fiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/amilarox/JMskU/).

Since all my project I started to use angulajs only I try to do it wisely and do not like how do I know.

I thought to add: `ng-model="btnStoreToDB"` and use this:

```
  if($scope.btnStoreToDB){
      var spinner = new Spinner().spin();
      $scope.btnStoreToDB.appendChild(spinner.el);
  }
```

but `$scope.btnStartUpload` is undefined. Suppose there is other way to fetch this button.

Please, help

Comment: You should have said in jQuery you just do `$('#....')`.JavaScript > jQuery ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a good question, and a very common situation.

The Angular way of doing this is to use `ng-show`, `ng-hide` or `ng-class` on or within your button.

One idea might be to use `ng-class` like so:

```
<button ng-class="{ useSpinner: btnStoreToDB }">...</button>
```

This will add the class `useSpinner` to the button when `btnStoreToDB` is true, and remove the class when btnStoreToDB is false.

Another way would be to use `ng-show` like this:

```
<button ...>
    <i class="icon-white icon-share-alt"></i>
    <span>Store to DB</span>
    <div class="spinner" ng-show="btnStoreToDb">...</div>
</button>
```

Now your view and controller are separated, and you are doing things the Angular Way.

Answer (score 3):

```
angular.element("#btnStoreToDB");
```

But here is more "angular" way

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.loading = false;

  $scope.send = function(){
    $scope.loading = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
      alert('finished');
      $scope.$apply($scope.loading = false);
    }, 2000);

  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button ng-click="send()">
      <img ng-show="loading" src="http://farmville-2.com/wp-content/plugins/farmvilleajpl/img/loadingbig.gif" width='10'>
      Send!    
</button>
```

**p.s.** Image from cutom source

**p.p.s** personally I usually use Twitter Bootstrap and there is a way to show spinners easier. like `<i class="icon-spin icon-spinner" ng-show="loading"></i>`

[See on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/XpqLGekdIMy5tiKiYCqt?p=preview)

Comment: You should add more explanations as how does this resolve the problem and why. It would make a better answer.

Comment: -1, i'm not interesting to use id (see the question). Your example shows how to add element to angular env. Sorry

Comment: You asked how can I get an element in a way like JS. I gave you answer. Thanks

Comment: @MaximShoustin, Added a bit more Angular way. Sorry for confusion

Comment: @HugoDozois, how do you think, does this (updated) version make sense?

Comment: @MaksymH. that looks way better